# Does an Azure Virtual Network have an SLA?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

As the title says, does an Azure virtual network resource have an SLA? I couldn't find anything.

I am basically comparing service endpoints to private endpoints, where the later belongs to the private link offering that comes with four-nine uptime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hit on Google : [No](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/190988/what-is-the-sla-on-a-vnet-virtual-network.html#:%7E:text=%40TimBraes%2D6697%2C%20AFAIK%2C,those%20resources%20within%20a%20boundary.).

> AFAIK, there is no defined SLA for Azure VNET. Azure Virtual Network is just a private IP block where all your resources can be deployed for private connectivity and secure those resources within a boundary. Virtual Network itself will never go down or experience outage, All the resources or services associated to the VNet may experience outage when a specific regional datacenter is down.

> This is the reason there is no charge for using Azure VNet or data transfer within a VNet, it's free of cost. Standard charges are applicable for resources, such as Virtual Machines (VMs) and other services within VNET boundary. Hence, we don’t have any SLA for Vnet.